# Django: Storing values into MySql from Templates

Tags: mysql, django

I have used a checkbox in my html template, On submit, i want to store these Boolean values into the MySql Table. Please advice me on, How should i code my views such that it accepts values from Templates and stores it to the database. Also suggest , if any alternative method is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order to store data into models from the user input, django provides a very good form API called ModelForm.

Documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/ clearly illustrates how to do it.

Essentially, you create a form and tell it, the model (which is your mysql table) you need to save it's data to and its all done for you. After validating.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to becomingGuru's answer I think you have to learn how [data is transported via HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods) and [HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) work, i.e. how to process user submitted data at the server side. This is not Django related.

But in Django you can access the data submitted in the views via

```
request.POST['parameter_name'] # for POST data
# or
request.GET['parameter_name'] # for GET data
# or
request.REQUEST['parameter_name'] # combined list these parameters
```

then you can store them in your database.